# starting CQ in Debug mode. What happens with forking

Tags: aem

I am pretty much interested in knowing that what happens to JVM forking when we start CQ in debug mode. I have gone through Adobe websites, but i am not much clear.
Does we have to use -nofork option?? or it automatically does this.

As of now, i understand it as this-

1. start CQ in debug mode with command line using this parameter:
    java -Xmx8192M  -agentlib:jdwp=transport........ -jar cq-author-4502.jar( nofork is not used )
2. CQ is started.
3. CQ forks a new JVM process *even if* I have given too much of memory to this command.
4. i use -nofork, but i start getting outofmemory errors. Why???

can i get a good to understand  explaination about this?

Comment: yes we have to use -nofork

Comment: @Abie , can you explain a bit more? i have updated my question

Comment: yes, sure... get me some time, need to do some home work regarding this, may be then we can discuss more. apologies for delay...

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have to use -nofork option?

No, but if you debug on a specific port it forces forking! (ensure Xmx is BEEG) 

If you run java -jar << AEM >>.jar --help on the jar file you get the following:

```
-debug << port >> <br/>
Enable Java Debugging on port number; forces forking
```

Lots of articles and overlaps, but hope this answers and gives food for thought.

Good article as well:
http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2012/03/09/cq5-5-how-to-start-the-server-in-debug-mode/

Answer (score 0):

If you run java -jar AEM.jar --help on the jar file you get:

```
    -debug <port>
Enable Java Debugging on port number; forces forking
```

It means it will fork a child process.
If you want to prevent forking, then use -nofork command line option with high memory size.